# What is the purpose of libimf.so?

Tags: libraries, shared-library, intel-graphics

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and am having various issues with `libimf.so` (see my questions on Ask Ubuntu: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802585/x-windows-hanging-during-ubuntu-boot), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604470/with-ubuntu-14-04-i-get-errors-related-to-qgis-when-i-type-sudo-apt-get-dist-upg)). While waiting to sort those issues out, I am trying to figure out what `libimf.so` is actually for.

Googling `libimf.so` is not helpful, so can anyone tell me what the `libimfo.so` shared library is for? My Ubuntu cannot find this shared library anywhere else except under the Intel compiler distribution under `/opt`.

Comment: `libimf.so` : ? Could be  `intel-icc9-libs` ? : "This package includes the shared and static libraries required to
run MySQL compiled with the Intel(R) icc 9.0 compiler."

Comment: @KnudLarsen - it is used beyond MySQL. It is used by the OS apparently. I need to know why.

Comment: What's the location ? How was it installed ? Please check if it's from a package.deb : `dpkg -S [location]/libimf.so`

Comment: @KnudLarsen - currently I can find it only under /opt/intel and so i do not think it Ubuntu installed it. I believe it came with the intel compiler

Comment: The purpose of `libimf.so` : All code compiled with the Intel `icc` will depend on libimf.so. ... Just like code compiled with `gcc` depends on `libgcc_s.so.1`

Comment: @KnudLarsen - OK What does it do though ? If you know what it does answer my question on AU - http://askubuntu.com/questions/802585/x-windows-hanging-during-ubuntu-boot

Comment: Not libgcc, but libm.so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is the [Intel Math Library](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522653). It contains optimized versions of functions such as sin, pow, etc typically found in libm. It is needed by software built with the intel compiler unless steps were taken to link it statically.